# Solving for $t_1$ & $t_2$ in the system $X_{p1}+t_1X_{d1}=X_{p2}+t_2X_{d2}$, $Y_{p1}+t_1Y_{d1}=Y_{p2}+t_2Y_{d2}$, $Z_{p1}+t_1Z_{d1}=Z_{p2}+t_2Z_{d2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have a system

$$\begin{align}
X_{p1} + t_1 X_{d1} &= X_{p2} + t_2 X_{d2}\\
Y_{p1} + t_1 Y_{d1}\, &= Y_{p2}\, + t_2 Y_{d2}\\
Z_{p1} + t_1 Z_{d1} &= Z_{p2} + t_2 Z_{d2}
\end{align}$$

and I can't solve it for $t_1$ and $t_2$.

I came to the monster fractions and stuck

**UPD**
$$
Y_{p1} + t_1 Y_{d1} = Y_{p2} + \frac{(X_{p1} + t_1 X_{d1} - X_{p2}) Y_{d2}}{X_{d2}}\\
t_1 Y_{d1} = Y_{p2} + \frac{X_{p1}Y_{d2} + t_1X_{d1}Y_{d2} - X_{p2}Y_{d2}}{X_{d2}}\\
t_1 Y_{d1} - \frac{t_1X_{d1}Y_{d2}}{X_{d2}} = Y_{p2} + \frac{X_{p1}Y_{d2} - X_{p2}Y_{d2}}{X_{d2}}\\
t_1 = \frac{Y_{p2} + \frac{X_{p1}Y_{d2} - X_{p2}Y_{d2}}{X_{d2}}}{(Y_{d1}-\frac{X_{d1}Y_{d2}}{X_{d2}})}
$$

Comment: Solve it like you would solve any linear system. For example, eliminate $t_2$ between the first two equations, then you get an equation in $t_1$ alone. Solve it for $t_1$, then calculate $t_2$, then substitute both in the 3rd equation to check whether the system is consistent.

Comment: Why don't use $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$?

Comment: @dxiv could you please show it in the answer. I don't get it

Comment: @Herrgott From the first equation $t_2 = \big(t_1 X_{d1} + X_{p1} - X_{p2}) \,/\, X_{d2}$, then substitute that $t_2$ in the second equation and get a linear equation in $t_1$. Then follow the rest of steps from my first comment. If you get stuck along the way, [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4133513/edit) the question to show where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: @dxiv this is the exact place. After i substitute that expression in the (2) equation it becomes huge and I can't take $t_2$ out of there. Give me some time to update the question

Comment: @dxiv i've updated the question. Could you check if it correct? Can it be simplified?

Comment: @Herrgott That looks about right. One way to make the expressions simpler is to merge the constant terms together by defining for example $X_{p12} = X_{p1} - X_{p2}$ etc, then $t_1 = \dfrac{X_{p12} Y_{d2} - X_{d2} Y_{p12}}{X_{d2} Y_{d1} -  X_{d1} Y_{d2}}$.